# SQLHelper Class - ExecuteNonQuery Code Modification

Tags: .net, sqlhelper

I am just browsing the code in the SQLHelper Class V2 and I notice the following

```
    public static int ExecuteNonQuery(SqlTransaction transaction, CommandType commandType, string commandText, params SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
    {
        if( transaction == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "transaction" );
        if( transaction != null && transaction.Connection == null ) throw new ArgumentException( "The transaction was rollbacked or commited, please provide an open transaction.", "transaction" );

        // Create a command and prepare it for execution
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        bool mustCloseConnection = false;
        PrepareCommand(cmd, transaction.Connection, transaction, commandType, commandText, commandParameters, out mustCloseConnection );

        // Finally, execute the command
        int retval = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Detach the SqlParameters from the command object, so they can be used again
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        return retval;
    }
```

Is there a reason why the command wasn't within a "Using Bolck"? I see the use of the"Using Block" elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Where's this code from? What is SQLHelper?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that its because the command is used throughout the scope of the function, so it would just add extra code. Different developer preferring different implementations.